# Computer won't start upon new hard drive install

Tags: hard-drive, boot, power-supply

I installed a new hard drive in my desktop. It is the third drive installed in the computer. However the computer won't turn on anymore. The power indicator on the motherboard is lit red. I have already tried removing the hard drive but the computer will not start. If it matters it is a home built computer with an Asus motherboard.

Comment: Check this troubleshooting guide from [tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1893016/post-system-boot-video-output-troubleshooting-checklist.html).

Comment: Did you bump any connections? Does disconnecting the drive help? Does disconnecting all non-critical connections help?

Comment: @Twisty Impersonator. I will check all the connections.

Comment: Are you sure the power supply can support another device?

Answer (score 2):

Sure enough after looking at the connections. The power connections to the motherboard were loose. Tightened them and it booted ok.